# Issue with css placement in rails (using bootstrap)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose we have the following in stylesheets/myFilename.css.scss:

```
...

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
}

...
```

This will not perform as intended unless I modify it to:

```
...

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none !important;
}

...
```

However, if instead of having the css in the stylesheets folder, I put it directly into myfile.html.erb, I don't need `!important`.  How do I resolve this issue?

I assume that it has something to do with the ordering/combination of the css from stylesheets, but I'm not certain.  If anyone could shed some light, that would be great.

Comment: You need to make rule more specific. http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because CSS has a cascading hierarchy that it follows. In your case:

1. Inline styles
2. Internal stylesheet
3. External stylesheet

Internal stylesheet is prioritized more than External stylesheets, so if you declare it directly in your html, you won't need **!important** anymore to override any other external stylesheets that cause this conflict.

Further reading on css hierarchy and specifity:

> http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
>   http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

If you need a **!important** in your external stylesheet, that means you have a css conflict somewhere else. Being more specific in your selector is always better than using !important, so you can do it like so:

```
/*Use an ID in your html*/
#my_id .carousel-control.left, #my_id .carousel-control.right {
   background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add your stylesheets/myFilename.css.scss file after the main stylesheet.
Suppose, your all css style getting from styleshees/style.css

Now your should write (stylesheets/myFilename.css.scss) it after that ( styleshees/style.css) in your index or associate header file.

Example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styleshees/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/myFilename.css.scss">
```

not

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/myFilename.css.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styleshees/style.css">
```